# How to change color of Pay Button in Stripe Pop-up?

Tags: jquery, html, popup, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe payment method in my leadpages, it is working well. I just want to change the color of the Pay button as shown in attached image.

[image]

and here is the code used to show popup

```
<script>
    var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: '[KEY]',
        image: 'https://www.emotionacademy.com.au/images/emotion-academy-logo.png',
        locale: 'auto',
        token: function(token) {
            $( "#stripeToken" ).val( token.id);
            $( "#stripeEmail" ).val( token.email);
            $( "#paymentForm" ).submit();
        }
    });

        $( ".btn-price-table" ).click(function(event) {
            var price = $(this).closest('.pricing-table').find('.price span').text()*100;
            var title = $(this).closest('.pricing-table').find('.pricing-title').text().toUpperCase();

            handler.open({
                name: title,
                description: '',
                zipCode: true,
                currency: 'aud',
                amount: price
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) runs into its own secure iframe, and at this time there is no [configuration option](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple-options) to customize the color of the button.

Comment: What is interesting is that they seem to be using the "image" to generate a color that they use for the little icons (like the small card in the card number field). They could use that for the button color as well...